Why does the author's simple method work correctly? ("Introduction to Analysis I" by Mitsuo Sugiura.)
I am reading "Introduction to Analysis I" by Mitsuo Sugiura.

Suppose $n\geq 2$.

$\int\frac{dx}{(x-a)^n}=\frac{-1}{n-1}\frac{1}{(x-a)^{n-1}}$.
$\int\frac{x dx}{(x^2+b^2)^n}=\frac{-1}{2(n-1)}\frac{1}{(x^2+b^2)^{n-1}}$.



Proof of 2.
By substituting $x^2 = t$, it reduces to (1).

My proof of 2. is the following:

Let $f(x) := \frac{1}{x^n}$.
Then, $F(x):=\int f(x) dx=\frac{-1}{n-1}\frac{1}{x^{n-1}}$.
$\frac{x}{(x^2+b^2)^n}=xf(x^2+b^2)=xF'(x^2+b^2)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2xF'(x^2+b^2)$.
So, $\int\frac{xdx}{(x^2+b^2)^n}=\frac{1}{2}F(x^2+b^2)=\frac{-1}{2(n-1)}\frac{1}{(x^2+b^2)^{n-1}}$.

I guess the author’s proof of 2. is like the following：

$x^2=t$.
$2xdx=dt$.
So, $\int\frac{x dx}{(x^2+b^2)^n}=\int\frac{\frac{1}{2}dt}{(t+b^2)^n}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{-1}{n-1}\frac{1}{(x+b^2)^{n-1}}=\frac{-1}{2(n-1)}\frac{1}{(x^2+b^2)^{n-1}}$.

But why does this work correctly?
I attempted to justify the author's proof:

By the definition of an indefinite integral,
$\int\frac{xdx}{(x^2+b^2)^n}=\int_{a}^{x}\frac{tdt}{(t^2+b^2)^n}$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$.
Suppose $x\geq a\geq 0$.
Let $t=\sqrt{s}$.
$\frac{dt}{ds}=\frac{1}{\frac{ds}{dt}}=\frac{1}{2t}$.
$\frac{tdt}{(t^2+b^2)^n}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2tdt}{(t^2+b^2)^n}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2t\frac{1}{2t}ds}{(s+b^2)^n}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{ds}{(s+b^2)^n}$.
$\int_{a}^{x}\frac{tdt}{(t^2+b^2)^n}=\int_{a^2}^{x^2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{ds}{(s+b^2)^n}$.
And by 1., $\int_{a^2}^{x^2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{ds}{(s+b^2)^n}=[\frac{-1}{2(n-1)}\frac{1}{(s+b^2)^{n-1}}]_{s=a^2}^{s=x^2}=\frac{-1}{2(n-1)}\frac{1}{(x^2+b^2)^{n-1}}-\frac{-1}{2(n-1)}\frac{1}{(a^2+b^2)^{n-1}}$.
If we ignore the constant term, we get $\int\frac{x dx}{(x^2+b^2)^n}=\frac{-1}{2(n-1)}\frac{1}{(x^2+b^2)^{n-1}}$.


Suppose $x\geq 0$ and $a < 0$.
$\int_{a}^{x}\frac{tdt}{(t^2+b^2)^n}=\int_{a}^{0}\frac{tdt}{(t^2+b^2)^n}+\int_{0}^{x}\frac{tdt}{(t^2+b^2)^n}$.
We can ignore $\int_{a}^{0}\frac{tdt}{(t^2+b^2)^n}$ because it is a constant.
We compute $\int_{0}^{x}\frac{tdt}{(t^2+b^2)^n}$.
Let $t=\sqrt{s}$.
$\frac{dt}{ds}=\frac{1}{\frac{ds}{dt}}=\frac{1}{2t}$.
$\frac{tdt}{(t^2+b^2)^n}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2tdt}{(t^2+b^2)^n}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2t\frac{1}{2t}ds}{(s+b^2)^n}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{ds}{(s+b^2)^n}$.
$\int_{0}^{x}\frac{tdt}{(t^2+b^2)^n}=\int_{0}^{x^2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{ds}{(s+b^2)^n}$.
And by 1., $\int_{0}^{x^2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{ds}{(s+b^2)^n}=[\frac{-1}{2(n-1)}\frac{1}{(s+b^2)^{n-1}}]_{s=0}^{s=x^2}=\frac{-1}{2(n-1)}\frac{1}{(x^2+b^2)^{n-1}}-\frac{-1}{2(n-1)}\frac{1}{(b^2)^{n-1}}$.
If we ignore the constant term, we get $\int\frac{x dx}{(x^2+b^2)^n}=\frac{-1}{2(n-1)}\frac{1}{(x^2+b^2)^{n-1}}$.


Suppose $0>x>a$.
Let $t=-\sqrt{s}$.
$\frac{dt}{ds}=\frac{1}{\frac{ds}{dt}}=\frac{1}{2t}$.
$\frac{tdt}{(t^2+b^2)^n}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2tdt}{(t^2+b^2)^n}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2t\frac{1}{2t}ds}{(s+b^2)^n}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{ds}{(s+b^2)^n}$.
$\int_{a}^{x}\frac{tdt}{(t^2+b^2)^n}=\int_{a^2}^{x^2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{ds}{(s+b^2)^n}$.
And by 1., $\int_{a^2}^{x^2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{ds}{(s+b^2)^n}=[\frac{-1}{2(n-1)}\frac{1}{(s+b^2)^{n-1}}]_{s=a^2}^{s=x^2}=\frac{-1}{2(n-1)}\frac{1}{(x^2+b^2)^{n-1}}-\frac{-1}{2(n-1)}\frac{1}{(a^2+b^2)^{n-1}}$.
If we ignore the constant term, we get $\int\frac{x dx}{(x^2+b^2)^n}=\frac{-1}{2(n-1)}\frac{1}{(x^2+b^2)^{n-1}}$.


Suppose we must compute $\int\frac{15x^4+4x^3+12x^2+2x+5}{(3x^5+x^4+4x^3+x^2+5x+b^2)^n}dx$.
Then, I guess the author's proof is the following:

By substituting $3x^5+x^4+4x^3+x^2+5x=t$, it reduces to (1).

Why does the author's simple proof work correctly?

If the author has already proved 1, any integral that can be changed (by a substitution) to the form of 1 can be solved by just applying the formula of 1. That is why author's proof works correctly. Then, the proof of 2 is done when you can reduce the integral to the form of 1.
So, if $2xdx = dt$ then
$$ \int \dfrac{xdx}{(x^2+b^2)^n} = \int \dfrac{\frac{1}{2}dt}{(t+b^2)^n} = \dfrac{1}{2} \int \dfrac{dt}{(t-(-b^2))^n}$$
Apply 1 to solve the integral (of course, $a=-b^2$):
$$ \dfrac{1}{2} \int \dfrac{dt}{(t-(-b^2))^n} = \dfrac{1}{2} \left( \dfrac{-1}{n-1} \dfrac{1}{(t-(-b^2))^{n-1}} \right) = \dfrac{-1}{2(n-1)} \dfrac{1}{(x^2+b^2)^{n-1}}$$
